# import formula from corrupt / large excel workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to import formula from a closed Excel workbook that has gotten overly large and hence wont open without crashing Excel.  I have a copy of the data but want to get at the formula in one of the tables inside.  Most of the solutions I have seen involve extracting data (which I have) or opening the workbook in VBA (which I cant) Does anyone have any thoughts that would help me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is version dependant, but it works on Excel 2007.

You can open the file using an archive tool (7-Zip, WinRar), your data will be stored in a sub-folder, "xl/worksheets/[sheet name]".

The data is stored as XML, which you can open using notepad or an XML reader if you have one.

Searching for *'<c r="A1">'* should take you to the node for cell A1.

Comment: This may work for `.pptx` files (although, if the file cannot be opened in PowerPoint, it may be corrupt).  It will definitely not work for `.ppt` files (without the `x`).  The same is true for `.doc`, `.docx`, `.xls`, and `.xlsx` files.  (The `x` stands for XML.)